# Porting a java interface to a scala trait with generics

Tags: generics, scala, parameterized, traits

I am a Scala newbie and I need to port part of a java application to scala.

I have the following java interface definition which is as follows:

```
public interface AccountDAO<A extends Account> extends CrudRepository<A, Integer> {
...
}
```

I am not sure how to implement the scala parameterized type according to the above java generics.

Here is my scala trait:

```
trait AccountDAO extends CrudRepository[A, Int] {
...
}
```

The problem I have is with the A.

Can anyone please advise?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The type parameter `A` and its subtype relationship to `Account` can be expressed as follows:

```
trait AccountDAO[A <: Account] extends CrudRepository[A, Int]
```